# How do I use 2 video boards on Dell XPS 15?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

Can I make Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 use both NVIDIA and Intel graphics processor? And how do I do that?

Comment: @Web-E please edit you answer ...check the link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee > http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work